# Cannot trigger jQuery .click() for button that contains certain text?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a button:

```js
$('.add_to_cart span:contains("Choose a Size")').click(function() {
  console.log("it has been clicked")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="submit" name="add" id="add-to-cart" class="action_button add_to_cart v-center" data-variantcount="44" data-label="Add to Cart" disabled="">
  <span class="text">Choose a Size</span>
</button>
```

However, this is never printing anything when I click it? You can see in this [image](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/619251004436774923/831855560030552074/unknown.png) that it is finding these elements but not triggering when clicked.

Comment: Why is the id `add-to-cart` but the button says _"Choose a Size"_?

Comment: I dynamically change the text-based off other variables, so that is redundant in this context.

Comment: @CeraMix I've noticed that your button is disabled, how do you expect to click it then?

Comment: The code works in Codepen, I get "it has been clicked" when clicking the button.

Comment: Can somebody else validate the suggested edit? So the code becomes a snippet and it becomes runnable directly

Answer (score 0):

Are you loading the script after the DOM has loaded?
Try:

```
$(function() {
  $('.add_to_cart span:contains("Choose a Size")').click(function () {
    console.log("it has been clicked")
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this?

```
$(document).on('click','.add_to_cart span:contains("Choose a Size")', function(){
console.log("it has been clicked");
});
```

Comment: Unless the button is not in the DOM then it would not change anything, and there is nothing in OP's code that suggest that the button is created after the DOM.

Comment: but initially we need to check the 'Button -> Span' having text like 'Choose Size' right?

Comment: Yes, but that does not change anything related to the DOM part

Comment: And also if we having that button in the same way means then "Console.log" should not show the alert.

Comment: What do you mean by `having that button in the same way`??  If I takes op's code and remove the disable part then It works just fine.

Comment: Could you paste that here? then I also can make some clarification .... :)

Comment: Look at op's question and try click the disabled button.

Comment: @RanjithKumar, I feel `.add_to_cart:not(:disabled) span:contains("Choose a Size")` selector would be a better choice,